# How to have always the same number of results in xpath even if some tags are not present?

Tags: xpath, xidel

I try to crawl data from a website. Target are sites where not always all details are given. For example one profile has `name, birthday` given and the other one only `name`.

I now try to grasp this tags with xidel and xpath which would work like a charm, when there wouldnt be sometimes a few tags missing (because a certain detail is not present)

So I ask for a solution where I can fill these notexistant tags with an empty one so that I end up with a set of data with the same length.

I convert the data to csv afterwards and when a tag is missing, all data are one column off.

My xidel requests looks like this:

```
xidel 'http://www.icaec.org/users/index' -f '//section[@id="content-area"]//article//h5/a' -e 'concat("`",join(//div[@id="members-info"]/(h5 | span) | //div[@class="row pic-professionsal-details"]/div[2]/div | //div[@class="row pic-professionsal-details"]/following-sibling::div/div[1]//div,"`;`"),"`")' | sed "s/\"/\\\"/g" | sed "s/\`/\"/g" >> icaec.csv
```

The xpath expression in question is this one:

```
'concat("`",join(//div[@id="members-info"]/(h5 | span) | //div[@class="row pic-professionsal-details"]/div[2]/div | //div[@class="row pic-professionsal-details"]/following-sibling::div/div[1]//div,"`;`"),"`")'
```

Which is more or less a concatenation of

```
//div[@id="members-info"]/(h5 | span)
//div[@class="row pic-professionsal-details"]/div[2]/div
//div[@class="row pic-professionsal-details"]/following-sibling::div/div[1]//div
```

Answer (score 2):

Xidel supports XPath and XQuery 3.0 so you can create sequences where you replace missing items with some default, for instance given

```
<items>
  <item>
    <foo>foo 1</foo>
    <bar>bar 1</bar>
  </item>
  <item>
    <foo>foo 2</foo>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bar>bar 3</bar>
  </item>
</items>
```

the XQuery 3.0 expression

```
string-join(//item!string-join(((foo, 'foo default')[1], (bar, 'bar default')[1]), ';'), '&#10;')
```

outputs

```
foo 1;bar 1
foo 2;bar default
foo default;bar 3
```

Comment: That looks great. But what is in the `foo` and `bar` variable you use in `(foo, 'foo default')[1]`?

Comment: I haven't used any variables in that expression, the input sample has `foo` and `bar` elements and `(foo, 'foo default')[1]` is constructing a sequence with the possible not existing `foo` element and the string constant `foo default` and then takes the first `[1]` value in that sequence which is just an XPath/XQuery idiom of selecting `foo` if it exists or taking a default. So for the first `item` `(foo, 'foo default')[1]` constructs a two item sequence with the existing `<foo>foo 1</foo>` element and the string default and selects that first item, the element.

Comment: right, I missed that. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: And for the third `item` which doesn't have a `foo` child element the expression `(foo, 'foo default')[1]` selects the string `foo default` as in that case it is the first and only item in the sequence constructed by `(foo, 'foo default')`.

Comment: I think I tried this already but whenever I do something like `(foo, "default")[1]` i get the error "invalid type for union". Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you want or need a union which is restricted to nodes? If you want CSV I would expect you to use a sequence with the comma operator `,` instead of the union operator `|`. Consider to edit your question and show a small but representative HTML sample you want to query, together with the result you want for that sample, then I am sure we can fix the expression. I am currently not sure which of your paths can select possibly not existing elements and which elements map to a line in the CSV.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128005/discussion-between-fuzzyma-and-martin-honnen).

Answer (score 1):

XPath is for ***selection*** of nodes that exist in an XML document.  You cannot select nodes that do not already exist.  (**Update**: But see [Martin Honnen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575927/290085) for how XQuery/XPath 3.0 can specify default values when creating a sequence.  Xidel this year has been updated with complete XQuery/XPath 3.0 support.)

XSLT is for ***transformation*** of XML documents and can rearrange nodes or create new nodes.  Your needs have progressed beyond selection to transformation.

Comment: I recommend [**Saxon**](http://www.saxonica.com/products/why-saxon.xml)